# Run command on next reboot (only)

Tags: cron

I've gone through lots of hunting to find a good way to run a command on reboot.  Most solutions suggest the use of crontab with an "@reboot" time specification.

I've wound up with the code below, however, it has one glaring issue that I'd like to have a nice fix for:

The cron job runs EVERY SINGLE TIME the system reboots, and that is not what is wanted.  The very hacky workaround is to have the script itself remove the crontab line included by this script, but that creates a very unclean dependency.

```
reboot_and_launch_setup() {
    # Get the command on reboot ready with cron
    if [[ -f "${DEP_SCRIPT}" ]]; then
        POST_REBOOT_CM="@reboot ${DEP_SCRIPT}"
        (crontab -u $(whoami) -l; echo "${POST_REBOOT_CM}" ) | crontab -u $(whoami) -
    else 
        echo "ERROR: The deployment script did not get installed."
        echo "ERROR: Expected to find deployment script, ${DEP_SCRIPT}"
        echo "ERROR: Check that the deployment script is included in the archive:"
        echo "ERROR:      --> ${PSA_DEPS_FILE}"
    fi
    reboot
}
```

And ideal solution would provide a command such as `at` with a `@reboot` time specification so that the command being run is only run once, upon the very next reboot.  Its almost like we need an enhancement to the `at` command to accept the same list of shortcuts accepted by cron.

Anyway, I digress... is there a way to do this, where the second script doesn't have to start off by removing itself from the crontab?

Comment: Some suggestions here [Linux: Schedule command to run once after reboot (RunOnce equivalent)](https://serverfault.com/questions/148341/linux-schedule-command-to-run-once-after-reboot-runonce-equivalent) - I quite like the look of [this one](https://serverfault.com/a/1099519/370258) but wonder if it could be better implemented using a systemd [Transient timer unit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/Timers#Transient_timer_units)

Comment: Interesting.  I like the look of the first one you mentioned too, other than potential conflicts with startup sequences.    The systemd-run command mentioned in the transient timer unit suggestion looks even more promising, but seems like I'm going to need help from someone very familiar with that system.  Its also nice, because if I need to it can potentially use systemd to solve startup sequence dependency issues...

Answer (score 0):

I think I would set this up as a proper service (systemd or otherwise), which, after it has done its "deployment thing" successfully, removes itself again.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the removing itself, as per the original post... however, there are some merits for my specific case to have a normal systemd unit, and part of that is that the startup sequence can redeploy the system if it is no longer installed (or intentionally removed for a clean slate)  If I can figure out a transient timer or similar for the reboot, these two approaches can probably be swapped out for one need vs the other.  Any pointers on where to start for one of these?  I did one a while ago, but it never quite worked as expected.

Comment: Alternative: Instead of self-removal, the service can safely self-disable (so it exists but won't run during subsequent boots). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197670/how-to-disable-a-service-without-using-systemctl-disable